# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table' and could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have created a project with SQL Server which the files:

UserDAO.java*

```
public class UserDAO 
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static 
    {
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<User> findAll()
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
        List<User> userList = crit.list();
        return userList;
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
public class UserService 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<User> listUsers = UserDAO.findAll();
        for(User u : listUsers)
        {
            System.out.println("User is = " + u.getUserName());
        }
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=happy</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">lm</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pp</property>
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
       <property name="show_sql">true</property>
       <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
       <mapping class="com.annotation.day1.entity.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

After running the project, the exception bellow displayed:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.id as id1_0_0_,
        this_.password as password2_0_0_,
        this_.userName as userName3_0_0_ 
    from
        User this_
Aug 07, 2016 9:29:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001
Aug 07, 2016 9:29:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    at com.annotation.day1.dao.UserDAO.findAll(UserDAO.java:74)
    at com.annotation.day1.service.UserService.main(UserService.java:24)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use square brackets (e.g. `[User]` instead of `User`). I would suggest not using "user" for a table name, given it's a reserved keyword in SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot ZLK for your help, it's solved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`USER`** is a [Reserve Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.90).aspx) and needs to be escaped in query using `square bracket []` while querying.

If you are using annotations, escape through single quotes. `''`, like below

```
@Table(name="`user`")
```

Also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502454/org-springframework-beans-notreadablepropertyexception-invalid-property-user/25504810#25504810) for similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Faced pretty similar issue, when Column name value has **space** in between.

Note : **Hibernate 5.3.7 with SQLServer 2014**

@Entity

@Table(name = "TableName")

public class Customer {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "cid")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int customerId;

@Column(name = "Customer Name")
private String customerName;

---
---
```

**ERROR:** 
[image]

**Solution 1 :** **Template Literals**

[image: @Table(name="<code>Customer Name</code>")]

**Solution 2:**

-We could remove the space or add '_' in between

**@Column(name = "CustomerName")** or **@Column(name = "Customer_Name")**

Note: **Name** is also a [reserved word](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) in SQLServer.